# How to free malloc arrays in an malloc array using struct

Tags: c

So lets say I have two structs and I created a malloc array of cacheSets and then created array of cacheLine using malloc in my struct cacheSet. How would I free all of those mallocs? Would just using free(cacheSet) be enough to free everything so I don't have a memory leak?

```
struct cacheLine
{
  int valid;
  int tag;
  int block;
  int age;
  int accessed;

};

struct cacheSet
{
  int setnum;
  int lastAssessed;
  int E;
  struct cacheLine *lines;
};
```

Comment: "So lets say I have two structs and I created a malloc array of cacheSets and then created array of cacheLine using malloc in my struct cacheSet". Let's not say. Let's show the exact code you have in mind. But the general rule is simple - for each `malloc` there must be exactly one `free`.

Comment: So i would loop through all my cacheSet's i have created and set each cacheLine free?

Comment: Yes it sounds like that's what you need. But as I said, if you show the precise code then we can give a more precise answer. Generally one would write a `cacheSet_free` function to encapsulate all that.

Comment: Yeah i don't have any code so far, I just wanted to make sure so I know for the future

Comment: But thank you for the clarification though!

Answer (score 0):

no, it won't be enough - you will have to manually free each element that `struct cacheLine *lines` points to before you free up `cacheSet`. Otherwise you will have memory leak.